# How to get value from other class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, e-commerce, stripe-payments

I'm not sure if I am phrasing this question correctly. I am using the Stripe API for a Harry Potter themed Rails online store demo app. I followed the Stripe boilerplate code, so I currently have the amount set at a hardcoded value of $1.00. In my shopping cart, there is a method that displays the total cost of all items in the cart. That works fine, but I can't figure out how to pass that value to the Charges controller so that it sets that as the amount of the payment.

I'm fairly new to Rails, so any helpful explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my charges/new.html.erb file:

```
<%= form_tag charges_path do %>
  <article>
    <% if flash[:error].present? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <p><%= flash[:error] %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <label class="amount">
      <span>Amount: $1.00</span>
    </label>
  </article>

  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="100"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
<% end %>
```

Here is my Charges controller:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
    include CurrentCart
    before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :create]

    def new
    end

    def create #METHOD IS CALLED AFTER PAYMENT IS MADE
     # Amount in cents
     @amount = 100

     customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
       :email => params[:stripeEmail],
       :source  => params[:stripeToken]
     )

     charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
       :customer    => customer.id,
       :amount      => @amount,
       :description => 'Witch or Wizard',
       :currency    => 'usd'
     )

     Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id]) 

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
      redirect_to new_charge_path
    end 

end
```

Here is my carts/show.html.erb file:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h2>My Cart</h2>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total Price in Galleons</th>
            <th>Total Price in Muggle Currency</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
            <%= render(@cart.line_items) %>
            <tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price * 7.35) %></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </thead>
</table>

<br>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= link_to 'Back', products_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary whiteText' %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= link_to "Checkout", new_charge_path, :class => 'btn btn-success whiteText' %>

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <%= link_to 'Empty Cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to empty your cart?'}, :class => 'btn btn-danger whiteText' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my Carts controller:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart

  # GET /carts
  # GET /carts.json
  def index
    @carts = Cart.all
  end

  # GET /carts/1
  # GET /carts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /carts/new
  def new
    @cart = Cart.new
  end

  # GET /carts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /carts
  # POST /carts.json
  def create
    @cart = Cart.new(cart_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /carts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cart.update(cart_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cart, notice: 'Cart was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @cart }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @cart.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /carts/1
  # DELETE /carts/1.json
  def destroy
    @cart.destroy if @cart.id == session[:cart_id]
    session[:cart_id] = nil
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Cart was emptied.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def update_quantity
    @line_item.update_attribute(:quantity)
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cart
      @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def cart_params
      params.fetch(:cart, {})
    end

    def invalid_cart
      logger.error "Attempt to access invalid cart #{params[:id]}"
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Invalid cart'
    end
end
```

Here is my Cart model:

```
class Cart < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

    def add_product(product)
        current_item = line_items.find_by(product_id: product.id)
        if current_item
            current_item.quantity += 1
        else
            current_item = line_items.build(product_id: product.id)
        end
        current_item
    end

    def total_price
       line_items.to_a.sum {|item| item.total_price} 
    end

    def convert_to_muggle(galleons)
        line_items.to_a.sum {|item| item.convert_to_muggle} 
    end    

end
```

And here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :charges
  resources :orders
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts
  devise_for :users
  match 'users/:id' => 'users#destroy', :via => :delete, :as => :admin_destroy_user
  resources :users, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]

  root 'products#index'

  resources :products

  controller :products do
    post '/products/destroy' => 'products#destroy', as: :destroy
    get '/products/add_to_cart' => 'products#add_to_cart', as: :add_to_cart
    get '/products/remove_from_cart' => 'products#remove_from_cart', as: :remove_from_cart
  end

  controller :line_items do 
    post '/line_items/increase_quantity' => 'line_items#increase_quantity', as: :increase_quantity
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Comment: your charges/new.html.erb is a little odd. Why is there a form_tag but no submit button?

Comment: There is a working button that gets rendered to the page. It's using the Stripe API to create the form.

Comment: Is this $1 referring to something different than the `data-amount` attribute you're already providing? Why not `data-amount='1'`?

Comment: Because the data amount attribute reads it as cents. So $1.00 is 100 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your charges_controller, change the amount:

```
@amount = @cart.total_price * 735
```

And your charges/new.html.erb:

```
<span>Amount: <%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price * 7.35) %></span>
```

and

```
data-amount="<%= @cart.total_price * 735 %>"
```

Let me know if that helps.